# c#: beginners CLASS constructor problems

Tags: c#, constructor

```
public class ElapsedTime
{
    public int hours;
    public int minutes;
    public void ElapsedTime(int h, int m)
    {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
    }
}
```

from another event i am doing this:

```
    ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime();
```

how would i initialize the `h` and `m`?

when i try to do this: `BeginningTime.ElapsedTime(7, 7);`

it gives me this error:

> Error 1   'ElapsedTime': member names
>   cannot be the same as their enclosing
>   type

all i want is a class with a constructor that accepts initializing values. and i want to be able to call it.

**UPDATE:**

now i have :

```
 public class ElapsedTime
        {
            private int hours;
            private int minutes;
            public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)
            {
                hours = h;
                minutes = m;
            }
        }
```

its giving me that same erorr on `public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)`

Comment: By .NET conventions, local variables should start in lower case. You should also be making the two fields private and perhaps exposing them as read-only properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of a class needs to be of the same name of the class itself. Now, the parameters `h` and `m` make it a parameterized constructor. In order to initialize a instance of this class, you will need to specify values to those.

```
ElapsedTime beginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);
```

Calling the constructor through a variable is not doable:

```
ElapsedTime beginningTime;
beginningTime.ElapsedTime(7, 7); // This will cause an error, as your constructor isn't a method...
```

In inroder to be a class initializer, the constructor has no return type (neither `void`).

Of course, if you want a property which gives you the values under a certain format, you will need to expose a property which will provide you with the values you instantiated your instance:

```
public class ElapsedTime {
    public ElapsedTime(int h, int m) {
        Hours = h;
        Minutes = m;
    }

    public int Hours { get; private set; }
    public int Minutes { get; private set; }
    public string ElapsedTime {
        get {
            return string.Format("{0}:{1}", Hours, Minutes);
        }
    }
}
```

Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 6):

Leave out `void`.  By having it there, you're declaring it is a method, not a constructor.

```
public class ElapsedTime
{
    public int hours;
    public int minutes;
    public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)
    {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
    }
}
```

Then to create an instance is just a matter of calling the constructor.

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);
```

Comment: now i am getting this error on public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)

Comment: There shouldn't be an error the way this is written.  You should note that this class contains no additional methods (besides `ToString()` for example) and one constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Error 1 'ElapsedTime': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Comment: @jenny - Do you call it as Jeff showed i.e. ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);  ?

Comment: @Oren: I think jenny forgot to save the changes before compiling because it's working now.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is wrong. Constructors don't have a return type. It needs to look like this

```
public class ElapsedTime {
   private int hours;
   private int minutes;

   public ElapsedTime(int h, int m) {
     hours = h;
     minutes = m;
   }
}
```

and then you can create a new instance like this

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You meant the method would be a constructor, so it should not contain a return type (delete the `void`)
Now you can use:

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7,7);
```

You can't call the constructor after the class has been created.
Constructors are for giving the class it's `initial` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7,7);
```

ofcourse remove void from ElapsedTime()

Answer (score 1):

The member being referred to is the method `ElapsedTime()`.  Specifically, you have not created a constructor.  You have created a method with the name that the constructor would have.

Try removing the `void` in front of your method definition.  That will make it a .ctor.

Comment: now i am getting this error on public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have things set up indicates that you would like to pass some values `h` and `m` to the constructor when you create the object. You should do this:

```
public class ElapsedTime
{
    // you should probably makes these private
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    // I took out the "void" as it is not correct
    public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)
    {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
    }
}
```

And then you would do this to instantiate an object of class `ElapsedTime`:

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);
```

If you wanted to do things the way that you have it now (where you set the values of hours and minutes after you create a new instance of the object you should expose those `Fields` through `Properties`, like so:

```
Public int Hours
{
    set {
        hours = value;
    }
    get {
        return hours;
    }
}

Public int Minutes
{
    set {
        minutes = value;
    }
    get {
        return minutes;
    }
}
```

And then you could use these as follows:

```
ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);
BeginningTime.Hours = 7;
BeginningTime.Minutes = 7;
```

The above is equivalent to `ElapsedTime BeginningTime = new ElapsedTime(7, 7);`

so you'd end up with this in your class file:

```
public class ElapsedTime
{
    // you should probably makes these private
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    // I took out the "void" as it is not correct
    public ElapsedTime(int h, int m)
    {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
    }
    Public int Hours
    {
        set {
            hours = value;
        }
        get {
            return hours;
        }
    }

    Public int Minutes
    {
        set {
            minutes = value;
        }
        get {
            return minutes;
        }
    }
}
```